# Group Concat without conditionals

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I'm trying to rewrite my query to use columns instead of rows. I have this query:

```
mysql> SELECT r.id as responseId, a.id as answerId, o.id, optionId, q.label as questionLabel, o.label as optionLabel
    -> FROM answer a
    -> INNER JOIN question q ON questionId = q.id
    -> INNER JOIN answer_options_option ao ON a.id = ao.answerId
    -> INNER JOIN `option` o ON ao.optionId = o.id
    -> INNER JOIN response r ON a.responseId = r.id
    -> ORDER BY r.id, a.id, o.id;
```

Which gives me this output:

```
+------------+----------+----+----------+---------------+-------------+
| responseId | answerId | id | optionId | questionLabel | optionLabel |
+------------+----------+----+----------+---------------+-------------+
|          1 |        1 |  2 |        2 | Q1            | no          |
|          1 |        2 |  4 |        4 | Q2            | b           |
|          2 |        3 |  1 |        1 | Q1            | yes         |
|          2 |        4 |  3 |        3 | Q2            | a           |
|          2 |        4 |  4 |        4 | Q2            | b           |
|          2 |        4 |  5 |        5 | Q2            | c           |
+------------+----------+----+----------+---------------+-------------+
```

But I would like to get this output:

```
+------------+-----------+-------+
| responseId | Q1        | Q2    |
+------------+-----------+-------+
|          1 | no        | b     |
|          2 | yes       | a,b,c |
+------------+-----------+-------+
```

So I threw together this query:

```
mysql> SELECT r.id as responseId,
    -> IF(q.label = 'Q1', GROUP_CONCAT(o.label), NULL) as Q1,
    -> IF(q.label = 'Q2', GROUP_CONCAT(o.label), NULL) as Q2
    -> FROM answer a
    -> INNER JOIN question q ON questionId = q.id
    -> INNER JOIN answer_options_option ao ON a.id = ao.answerId
    -> INNER JOIN `option` o ON ao.optionId = o.id
    -> INNER JOIN response r ON a.responseId = r.id
    -> GROUP BY r.id;
```

But it gives me this output instead:

```
+------------+-----------+------+
| responseId | Q1        | Q2   |
+------------+-----------+------+
|          1 | no,b      | NULL |
|          2 | yes,a,b,c | NULL |
+------------+-----------+------+
```

Is it even possible to use `GROUP_CONCAT` like this? Is there another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Here's a [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pRBnPyiHLqEDEyJgiFtJub/0).

Comment: Thank you for providing a fiddle. It makes it *so* much easier to respond to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `GROUP_CONCAT` *outside* the conditional so that you aggregate the options based on the question instead of just getting the entire aggregated result based on the question value:

```
SELECT r.id as responseId,
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN q.label = 'Q1' THEN o.label END ORDER BY o.label) as Q1, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN q.label = 'Q2' THEN o.label END ORDER BY o.label) as Q2
FROM answer a
INNER JOIN question q ON questionId = q.id
INNER JOIN answer_options_option ao ON a.id = ao.answerId
INNER JOIN `option` o ON ao.optionId = o.id
INNER JOIN response r ON a.responseId = r.id
GROUP BY r.id;
```

Output:

```
responseId  Q1      Q2
1           no      b
2           yes     a,b,c
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pRBnPyiHLqEDEyJgiFtJub/1)